# Python 3, 5/2 when importing from module gives 2 and not 2.5

Tags: python, division

Im making a calculator program in python 3 and I have split the program into modules. I made a subtraction function in a module that just takes two numbers and divides with the normal / operator. However, it seems to be acting like / from python 2 and 5/2 gives me 2 and not 2.5. However, I tried making a new file where all it did is print(5/2) and that gave me 2.5. I tried reinstalling python to no avail. I have the newest version (3.4.3). Am I messing up somehow or is this a bug?

calculator:

```
import operation
import formula
import time
print("\n")
run = True
while run:
try:
    print("1: Addittion")
    print("2: Subtraction")
    print("3: Multiplication")
    print("4: Division")
    print("5: Advanced")
    print("6: Quit")
    print("\n")

    choice = int(input("What would you like to do? "))
    print("\n")

    if choice == 1:
        operation.add()

    elif choice == 2:
        operation.subtract()

    elif choice == 3:
        operation.multiply()

    elif choice == 4:
        operation.divide()

        try:
            answer = numberA / numberB

        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("ERROR: DIVIDE BY ZERO")
            print("\n")

        else:
            print("%d / %d = %d" % (numberA, numberB, answer))
            print("\n")

    elif choice == 5:
        print("1: Arithmetic Sequences")
        print("2: Geometric Sequences")
        print("3: Pythagorean Theorem")
        print("4: Median")
        print("5: Go Back")
        print("\n")

        choice = int(input("What would you like to do? "))
        print("\n")

        if choice == 1:
            formula.arithmetic()

        elif choice == 2:
            formula.geometric()

        elif choice == 3:
            formula.pythagorean()

        elif choice == 4:
            operation.median()

        elif choice == 5:
            pass

        else:
            print("ERROR: PLEASE ENTER A VALID OPTION (1-5)")
            print("\n")

    elif choice == 6:
        pass
        time.sleep(3)
        run = False

    else:
        print("ERROR: PLEASE ENTER A VALID OPTION (1-6)")
        print("\n")

except ValueError:
    print("\n")
    print("ERROR: PLEASE ONLY USE NUMBERS")
    print("\n")
```

module:

```
def divide():
numberA = int(input("What is the dividend? "))
numberB = int(input("What is the divisor? "))
print("\n")

try:
    answer = numberA / numberB

except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("ERROR: DIVIDE BY ZERO")
    print("\n")

else:
    print("%d / %d = %d" % (numberA, numberB, answer))
    print("\n")
```

note: the module actually had other equations in it (-, x, and +) but I didnt include them because I dont think you need them. Tell me if you want to see them

Comment: Could you post your code

Comment: you can use `5/2.0`, `5.0/2`, or just add `from __future__ import division` to the top of your python file.

Comment: @marmeladze Except he is using Python 3 and thus there is no need to make assurance double sure.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't type an two division operators?

Comment: I only used one /. Thanks for the quick replies tho

Comment: @Lord_Zane55 How is it working now?

Comment: How exactly are you running this script?  Are you loading it into a Python 3 session (IDLE or similar), or from the command line?  If from the command line, what command are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You formatting with the integer specifier. Try this method instead.

```
print('{} / {} = {}'.format(numberA, numberB, answer))
```

Comment: Im new to programming and python is my first langue btw. Idk what you mean by "You formatting with the integer specifier."

Comment: In your code you are printing a string where `%d` substitutes the values as integers.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `print("%d / %d = %f" % (numberA, numberB, answer))`

Comment: The use of `%f` denotes that you want to substitute the value as a floating point number.

Comment: Oh. Yeah thanks didnt know that. using %s instead of %d fixed it Edit: Didnt know about %f thanks

Comment: You should check out the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html?highlight=formatting#format-specification-mini-language) on the matter.